# Sick Of Medium.com Premium Content. Can I hide premium posts targeting a parent element of element with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, css

I've found that on all Premium posts they use an element with the `class ="svgIcon-use"`

```
<svg class="svgIcon-use" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15" style=""><path d="M7.438 2.324c.034-.099.09-.099.123 0l1.2 3.53a.29.29 0 0 0 .26.19h3.884c.11 0 .127.049.038.111L9.8 8.327a.271.271 0 0 0-.099.291l1.2 3.53c.034.1-.011.131-.098.069l-3.142-2.18a.303.303 0 0 0-.32 0l-3.145 2.182c-.087.06-.132.03-.099-.068l1.2-3.53a.271.271 0 0 0-.098-.292L2.056 6.146c-.087-.06-.071-.112.038-.112h3.884a.29.29 0 0 0 .26-.19l1.2-3.52z"></path></svg>
```

Is it possible to target and hide the post container...

```
<article class="extremePostPreview u-marginBottom48 uiScale uiScale-ui--small uiScale-caption--small"></article>
```

if `<svg class="svgIcon-use">` is present on the child?

Comment: Not using CSS, unfortunately.

Comment: `$('article').has('.svgIcon-use').hide();` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My updated js method with the new website is (for medium.com/tag/* page):

```
function hide() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("star-15px_svg__svgIcon-use").length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("star-15px_svg__svgIcon-use")[i] != "none") {
            document.getElementsByClassName("star-15px_svg__svgIcon-use")[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"
        }
    }
}
```

Then just run `hide()`
You can use an extension like [tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) to run the script automatically.

Since the home page is built slightly different you will need a different function (for medium.com home page):

```
functuon hide() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("star-15px_svg__svgIcon-use").length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("star-15px_svg__svgIcon-use")[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy & Paste the following code into your console when browsing a Medium page. The solution is in pure javaScript. It will hide all the premium articles:

```js
var premiumShit = document.body.querySelectorAll(".streamItem");
for(var counter = 0; counter < premiumShit.length; counter++){
    if(premiumShit[counter].innerHTML.includes("M7.438 2.324c.034-.099.09-.099.123 0l1.2 3.53a.29.29 0 0 0 .26.19h3.884c.11 0 .127.049.038.111L9.8 8.327a.271.271 0 0 0-.099.291l1.2 3.53c.034.1-.011.131-.098.069l-3.142-2.18a.303.303 0 0 0-.32 0l-3.145 2.182c-.087.06-.132.03-.099-.068l1.2-3.53a.271.271 0 0 0-.098-.292L2.056 6.146c-.087-.06-.071-.112.038-.112h3.884a.29.29 0 0 0 .26-.19l1.2-3.52z")){
        premiumShit[counter].style.opacity = "0"; premiumShit[counter].style.height = "0"
    }
}
```

The idea is that it iterates through each article element. If it finds that long string full of numbers (this is the path of the SVG star element you told us about) within the innerHTML of the article, it will set the opacity of that element to 0 and its height to 0 (don't use "display:none" because the page loads more articles when you use that; instead, use the opacity and height)

I know this solution is a dirty one, but hey: it's the only one which works no matter how many parents the SVG has and it doesn't require jQuery. To summarize, this is a solution will always work.

**EDIT:** unfortunately, if you scroll down the page, new articles won't load, so you have to reload the page each time you want to view more articles (and copy the paste code again in the JavaScript console, but it will be already in the memory of the JavaScript console, so all you need is to tap the arrow-up key on your keyboard once)

Comment: How on earth does this work (even on refresh) by hardcoding a target for **that string**? Is that string not autogenerated?

Comment: No, it's not :D

Comment: This string describes how the little SVG star at the bottom of each premium article is rendered, so it's not auto-generated. It's hardcoded to each premium article.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to jQuery, its [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest-selector) operator makes this easy.

```js
$(".svgIcon-use").each((i, e) => {
  $(e).closest("article").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  This one stays
</article>
<article>
  Hide this one
  <svg class="svgIcon-use" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15" style=""><path d="M7.438 2.324c.034-.099.09-.099.123 0l1.2 3.53a.29.29 0 0 0 .26.19h3.884c.11 0 .127.049.038.111L9.8 8.327a.271.271 0 0 0-.099.291l1.2 3.53c.034.1-.011.131-.098.069l-3.142-2.18a.303.303 0 0 0-.32 0l-3.145 2.182c-.087.06-.132.03-.099-.068l1.2-3.53a.271.271 0 0 0-.098-.292L2.056 6.146c-.087-.06-.071-.112.038-.112h3.884a.29.29 0 0 0 .26-.19l1.2-3.52z"></path></svg>
</article>
```

**EDIT:**

Most browsers now support the native [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) function, so here it is in straight javascript

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.svgIcon-use').forEach(e => {
    e.closest("article").style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  This one stays
</article>
<article>
  Hide this one
  <svg class="svgIcon-use" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15" style=""><path d="M7.438 2.324c.034-.099.09-.099.123 0l1.2 3.53a.29.29 0 0 0 .26.19h3.884c.11 0 .127.049.038.111L9.8 8.327a.271.271 0 0 0-.099.291l1.2 3.53c.034.1-.011.131-.098.069l-3.142-2.18a.303.303 0 0 0-.32 0l-3.145 2.182c-.087.06-.132.03-.099-.068l1.2-3.53a.271.271 0 0 0-.098-.292L2.056 6.146c-.087-.06-.071-.112.038-.112h3.884a.29.29 0 0 0 .26-.19l1.2-3.52z"></path></svg>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick with plain javascript the following may work for you assuming "article" is the immediate parent of the "svg"

```
document.querySelectorAll('.svgIcon-use').forEach(element => {
    element.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Here's a sample: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJzQex

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS only is not an option. With Javascript hiding the parent node can be accomplished.

```js
function hideThem() {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("svgIcon-use");
  for (element of elements) {
    element.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
article,
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: solid thin #eee;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <svg class="svgIcon-use" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15" style=""><path d="M7.438 2.324c.034-.099.09-.099.123 0l1.2 3.53a.29.29 0 0 0 .26.19h3.884c.11 0 .127.049.038.111L9.8 8.327a.271.271 0 0 0-.099.291l1.2 3.53c.034.1-.011.131-.098.069l-3.142-2.18a.303.303 0 0 0-.32 0l-3.145 2.182c-.087.06-.132.03-.099-.068l1.2-3.53a.271.271 0 0 0-.098-.292L2.056 6.146c-.087-.06-.071-.112.038-.112h3.884a.29.29 0 0 0 .26-.19l1.2-3.52z"></path></svg>
</article>

<div>
  <svg class="svgIcon-use" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15" style=""><path d="M7.438 2.324c.034-.099.09-.099.123 0l1.2 3.53a.29.29 0 0 0 .26.19h3.884c.11 0 .127.049.038.111L9.8 8.327a.271.271 0 0 0-.099.291l1.2 3.53c.034.1-.011.131-.098.069l-3.142-2.18a.303.303 0 0 0-.32 0l-3.145 2.182c-.087.06-.132.03-.099-.068l1.2-3.53a.271.271 0 0 0-.098-.292L2.056 6.146c-.087-.06-.071-.112.038-.112h3.884a.29.29 0 0 0 .26-.19l1.2-3.52z"></path></svg>
</div>

<button onclick="hideThem()">Click me</button>
```